# What does "make -j n V=m" mean?

Tags: command-line, compiling, make

I don't understand one of the commands for compiling openWRT.

What's the meaning of the command `make -j N V=m` when compiling openWRT?

As an example, `make -j8 V=99`.

Comment: Have you gone through the [wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/start)?

Comment: Yes, I did. I found a lot of articles where these commands are mentioned but It does not explain what does it mean... Or I missed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2 options available to `make` here are:

- `-j8`: This option specifies the number of jobs to run simultaneously. From the `make` man pages:

  ```
  -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
     Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more
     than one -j option, the last one is effective.  If the -j option is given  with-
     out  an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.
  ```
- `V=99`: This option controls the degree and type of verbosity that you will be exposed to during the `make` process. This is not specific to `make` itself but rather to the `OpenWrt` makefile. In the source see the file `include/verbose.mk` where the following links are made:

  ```
  - Verbose = V
  - Verbosity level 1 = w (warnings/errors only)
  - Verbosity level 99 = s (This gives stdout+stderr)
  ```

**References:**

- [OpenWrt - verbose.mk](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/include/verbose.mk?rev=31484)

Comment: So whats the difference between `V=99` and `V=s` ? Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @Tomas see edit